# How can I run my windows service as 64 bit

Tags: .net, service

I have a windows service. In the Properties I have the platform target set as X64. In my csproj file I have changed all instances of prefer32bit to false. I am installing the service with installutil.exe when I install and run my service it runs as 32 bit. I am currently building in debug mode. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the 64bit version of `installutil.exe` to install for 64bit. The normal 32bit version cannot do this.

You can find it in

> %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework**64**\ *$VERSION* \InstallUtil.exe

instead of

> %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ *$VERSION* \InstallUtil.exe

Comment: This was my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I will recommend to use sc.exe util https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490995.aspx. It will install windows service depending on platform target framework information you choose in Visual Studio.

[image]